# How to get the string value showing in Result and Messages Tab in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I can't seem to find the right answers in google or maybe failed to used the right keywords.

How can I get the string value that is being displayed in

1. Result Tab
2. Messages Tab

[image]

in SQL Server.

Any help is appreciated

**EDIT:**
I want to get the string value and store it in variable which is in a stored procedure.

**EDIT**
I want to catch the output message and store it in a variable. This will be handled by stored procedure. So I need an sql syntax to get the string from results tab and messages tab.

Comment: Do you need every message or just the rows affected ? The latter you can find in `select @@ROWCOUNT` immediate after executing your query

Comment: @SurajKumar Yes you're right I want to catch the output message and store it in a variable. This will be handled by stored procedure. So I need an sql syntax to get the string from results tab and messages tab.

Comment: Please add very relevant information like that in your question, not in comments. I did it for you now

Comment: @GuidoG You're right I could actually get what I want from messages tab using @@ROWCOUNT and will just manipulate/concatenate the string 'rows affected'. But there are instances that there are other messages info aside from it that will appear based on a given query.

Comment: As in intern, it is expected that you seek and receive both guidance and knowledge from your (giant, multi-national) firm and its employees. The people you work with directly are much better situated to answering questions and helping you to be successful. That's the whole point of an internship. Hopefully one of the things you should be learning is how to ask better questions. As a developer, you should understand that context is important. Your basic question is "how do i get something in sql server" - which doesn't make much sense. Your 3rd edit provided that important context.

Answer (score 1):

Get them from where? Let's assume you are writing a C# application and use ADO.NET to connect to the database.

In this case you can use [InfoMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.infomessage?view=netframework-4.7.2) event handler of the connection to get what you see in Messages. Write an event handler like this:

```
void InfoMessageHandler(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
}
```

And attach it to the event:

```
var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
connection.InfoMessage += InfoMessageHandler;
```

And about the results, you can use [SqlCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand?view=netframework-4.7.2) class to execute queries against the database and get results. For example:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection );
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT 'Sample value'";  
    MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without a lot of explanation not quite sure what your trying to achieve or why. But to answer simply use PRINT.

```
SELECT 'Sample Value'
```

and

```
PRINT 'Sample Value'
```

Will return what your after. You can also use PRINT with variables if your looking to return different messages as part of a larger statement

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @Message NVARCHAR(100) = N'SampleValue';
SELECT @Message;
PRINT @Message;
```

Answer (score 0):

The **Results** and **Messages** tabs are SSMS (the SQL client) views that are attached to different outgoing channels from the SQL Server.

All `SELECT` statements with no DML operation (insert, update, etc.) will go to the standard results outgoing channel and will be displayed in the **Results** tab on SSMS. These are *result sets*, so they are all tables with N columns and M rows.

[image]

The **Messages** results is usually ad-hoc information that clients might want, like warnings, amount of rows affected by DML operations and error messages.

[image]

You should use `SELECT` results, temporary tables or `OUTPUT` variables to transfer data between stored procedures and avoid using/parsing the messages for this reason. I highly recommend reading [this post](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html) about all possible ways on how to move data between stored procedures, with their pros and cons.

If you just need a literal value (just 1 row and 1 value), you can use a scalar function instead of a stored procedure:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetStringValue ()
RETURNS VARCHAR(100) AS
BEGIN
    RETURN 'Sample Value'
END

GO

SELECT dbo.GetStringValue() AS Result
```

[image]

Can assign the result to a variable like this:

```
DECLARE @Result VARCHAR(100) = dbo.GetStringValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PRINT keyword.
For example, you have to print alphabets A to Z :

```
Declare @start int

set @start=65

while(@start<91)


begin

print char(@start)

set @start =@start+1

end;
```

[image]